# How to configure MLflow and encapsulate it for multiple instances

Tags: python, class, encapsulation, multiple-instances, mlflow

I would like to learn how to configure MLflow within a class and encapsulate it so that I can create an object from the class to perform all standard MLflow commands, such as `my_mlflow_object.log_model` and `my_mlflow_object.log_metric`.

The goal is for a user to create multiple objects from this class and specify all configuration parameters during initialization. These objects should not interfere with each other.

I want to use the instances like this:

```
my_mlflow_class1 = MyMLflowClass(tracking_uri='...', experiment_name='...', ...)
my_mlflow_object1 = my_mlflow_class1.get_mlflow_object()

my_mlflow_class2 = MyMLflowClass(tracking_uri='...', experiment_name='...', ...)
my_mlflow_object2 = my_mlflow_class2.get_mlflow_object()

my_mlflow_object1.log_metric(...)
my_mlflow_object1.log_model(...)

my_mlflow_object2.log_metric(...)
my_mlflow_object2.log_model(...)
```

I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
import mlflow

class MyMLflowClass:
    def __init__(self, tracking_uri=None):
        self.mlflow = mlflow
        if tracking_uri:
            self.mlflow.set_tracking_uri(tracking_uri)

    def get_mlflow_object(self):
        return self.mlflow

my_mlflow_class1 = MyMLflowClass(tracking_uri="http://localhost:6001")
my_mlflow_object1 = my_mlflow_class1.get_mlflow_object()
print(my_mlflow_object1.get_tracking_uri())

my_mlflow_class2 = MyMLflowClass(tracking_uri="http://localhost:6002")
my_mlflow_object2 = my_mlflow_class2.get_mlflow_object()
print(my_mlflow_object2.get_tracking_uri())

print(my_mlflow_object1.get_tracking_uri())
```

The output was:

```
http://localhost:6001
http://localhost:6002
http://localhost:6002
```

As you can see, the objects are interfering with each other.

What should the `MyMLflowClass` design be to ensure that configurations do not conflict among instances of this class, while still allowing the execution of all standard MLflow commands?